# No module name _tkinter error while tkinter is installed

Tags: python, tkinter

When trying to run my python 3 program that uses matplotlib via the command line, I get the following error:

```
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

The same happens when simply inputting:

```
>>>import tkinter
```

Suggested fixes such as installing python3-tk, python3.5-tk or python3.6-tk do not work, the result is:

```
python3.6-tk is already the newest version (3.6.6-1+xenial1).
```

and using matplotlib.use('agg') does not work as I need to output figures:

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
```

with pip install tkinter, python-tk or python3-tk the result is :

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-tk (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python3-tk
```

I also tried updating and reinstalling python3 but nothing seems to work (version 3.6.4). Could it be that python-tk is version 3.6.6 and my python 3.6.4?

Is there any other method I can try?

Comment: If you can't make it work by any other means, there is always the Python source install. That will work. Take care that 3.7 requires an updated openssl and that's important for pip and other things network related..